# Bootstrap col does not fill 100 width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my col, fill 100% width, when screensize is below 1024 px, but for some reason, i can't make it fill 100% to the right. I have here a picture of the result i'm getting now:
[image]

As you see, it goes all the way to the left, by adding `margin-left: -30px` But when i try to do the same, just with right, it wont take any effect.

Here is my code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
.Menu100Width {
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-right: -60px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And this is my div:

```
<div class="row col-lg-5 col-md-12 Menu100Width">
                <div id="MenuKort">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <hr style="float: none; margin-bottom: 25px; width: 100%;" />
                        <h1 id="cocktailsOverskrift">Cocktails</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div id="MenuKortIndhold">
                        <h3>Mojito</h3>
                        <hr style="margin-top: 7px;" /><br />
                        <span class="DrinkTekst">
                            Angostura Reserva Rom & Bitters - Danskvand - Frisk Lime & Mynte- Rørsukker - Knust is
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the margin to 0 instead?

Comment: I have, but adding Margin: 0; just put it whole thing in the center, still with a margin for some reason.

Comment: Next I would try having the ROW in its own div wrapping the COL's since that is the proper format.

Comment: I feel stupid now. I found the error. The error is that it's wrapped inside of a container-fluid. So i just set the padding: 0 for the fluid, and it works perfectly..

Comment: I see the row tag, is missplaced, i fixed that now :)